# Как остановить основной поток?

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, hotkeys

Есть в программе `keyboard.wait()`, который блокирует основной поток. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на Ctrl + Q совершался выход из основого потока. Как это реализовать?

```
import keyboard
import sys

def quit_prog():
    sys.exit()

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + Q', quit_prog)
keyboard.wait()
```

Вот сам код. Пытаюсь выйти из программы полностью нажав Ctrl + Q, но это не даёт никакого результата, т.к. `keyboard.wait()` полностью блокнул основной поток

Comment: Предоставьте минимально воспроизводимый пример кода.

Comment: @Александр, извиняюсь, что сразу не сделал Поздно было, когда задавал вопрос, тупанул чуток) Сейчас добавил всё

Comment: Не используйте wait, так.

Comment: @Александр, а как мне тогда зациклить программу? Она вся консольная, мне нужны горячие клавиши для управления ею. Другого варианта не нашёл...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотря, что вы пытаетесь воспроизвести. Судя по вашему коду, я бы сделал так:

```
import keyboard
import sys

def quit_prog():
    print("вы вышли из программы")
    sys.exit()

print("Выйти из программы: Ctrl + Q")
keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
quit_prog()
```

или вот еще вариант, я так понимаю именно управлять надо.

```
import keyboard
def foo():
    print('hi')

def foo2():
    print('Привет')

def foo3():
    print('Привет еще раз')


keyboard.add_hotkey('space + 1', foo)
keyboard.add_hotkey('space + 2', foo2)
keyboard.add_hotkey('space + 3', foo3)

keyboard.wait("Ctrl + q")
print('Любой код, в том числе и выход')
```